# HTML5 Geolocation, JavaScript, and Storing in Database

Tags: javascript

The following code is JavaScript in a JSP. I want to store the user’s latitude and longitude locations in a MySQL database by setting the value of two hidden fields on the HTML (called “latitude” and “longitude”). However, when the parameters "latitude" and "longitude" are sent to the database, they are null! Why doesn’t this code work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//in my onSubmit() JavaScript function 
latitude = position.coords.latitude;
longitude = position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById("latitude").value = String(latitude);
document.getElementById("longitude").value = String(longitude);
document.getElementById("study_session_form").action = "CreateStudySessionServlet";
document.getElementById("study_session_form").submit();

//in my HTML
<td><input type="hidden" id="latitude" /></td>                   
<td><input type="hidden" id="longitude" /></td>
<td><button id="submit_button” onclick="onSubmit();">Submit</button></td>
```

Comment: have you tried by using `parseFloat(latitude)` ? And the ìnput` field needs a `name` attribute to get to the value using post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set `name` attribute, ID's are not sent during form submission. E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude" />
```

Comment: Thanks! As you can probably tell I'm still new to this.